# Would this scenario classify as "not very dense graph"?

Tags: data-structures, graph, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

Based on these infos : **181 047 vertices** and **907 601 edges** does this classify as not very dense ? In french we say "not very dense" but i am not sure in english.

Let me explain you why i am asking you this.

I currently have a shortest path algorithm implemented with Dijkstra algorithm.

I have to optimize it, i found that **Dijkstra with min heap** beats normal Dijkstra by far. ( At least for my problem since i tried it.)

But one of the required property to implement Dijkstra algorithm with min heap is that the graph must be not very dense but i am confuse with what that means, i've seen a lot of definitions but nothing answers my question.

I also seen this definition somewhere : you can use dijkstra min heap **If your E is sufficiently smaller compared to** **V (as in E << V² / logV)**  So by this definition it would mean that i can't use Dijkstra with min heap but i did it and have a way faster algorithm so i am confused.

But E << V² doesn't tell me anything. ( what does that mean)

So i would like if someone could tell me based on the number of edges and vertices, if the graph qualify as "not so dense" if not is it dense or parse and why ?

Also i would like to know why we can use dijkstra min heap based on the number of edges and vertices.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The word is "sparse".  Apart from that, there are many confusing parts to this question. Dijkstra's algorithm with a min heap is normal, so what do you mean by "normal Dijkstra"?  It also works for any density.  Why do you think you can't use a min heap with dense graphs?

Comment: @MattTimmermans  By normal Dijkstra i meant that it has nothing fancy (it's an algo given by our teacher and we need to optimize it). I will quote my teacher note : " Dijkstra with min heap is only an advantage when the graph is not very dense" So my question is with these numbers of edge and vertices, is the graph dense or parse like you say and can i use the min heap algorithm for it ? ( i guess yes because i tried it and get a very better results) But i would like to have an explanation to why i can use it. (does it qualify to "not very dense") ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think the original Dijkstra was the one with the heap, with time O((v+e)log v). The O(v^2) came later (and the Fibonacci heap O(e+v log v) later still). You can always use the heap version, of course, but with e=v^2 it is less efficient than O(v^2) asymptotically and worst case. The two qualifiers there are important. On your data and with your implementation, the heap version might be the better choice. Not all data is worst case, and quite often a “worse” general algorithm can be faster when your data has a particular form. Think insertion sort on sorted data.

Comment: There is usually more to the complexity than just the numbers. You can have a huge and dense graph with a single path from source to target, and you can find that path in linear time if you are lucky and always pick a node that is one closer from the heap (and stop when you find the target). Any particular graph doesn’t say much about how the algorithm works in general and vice versa. The “worse” algorithm can easily be better for your data.

Comment: Oh, by "nothing fancy" you mean doing a linear search to find the next node...  That can be faster if E/V > V / log V or thereabouts.